# need to add data to rows for each month of the year

Tags: hive

I have a table where there is a transaction for each location under different billing codes, if there is a transaction under one billing code in one particular month of the year and if the billing code is discontinued in next month then the final transaction table should have both new billing code as well discontinued billing code for next 12 months (YTD transactions)

the Input table looks like this

| Year | LocationID | Month | invoiceID | code | amt1 | amt ytd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 6394 | 1 | 101 | F | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 1 | 101 | G | 10 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 2 | 102 | F | 2 | 3 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 3 | 103 | F | 3 | 6 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 4 | 104 | F | 4 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 5 | 105 | F | 5 | 15 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 6 | 106 | F | 2 | 17 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 6 | 106 | G | 1 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 7 | 107 | F | 2 | 19 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 8 | 108 | F | 3 | 22 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 9 | 109 | F | 1 | 23 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 10 | 1010 | F | 2 | 25 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 11 | 1011 | F | 1 | 26 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 12 | 1012 | F | 3 | 29 |

my expected output is

| Year | LocationID | Month | invoiceID | code | amt1 | amt ytd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 6394 | 1 | 101 | F | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 1 | 101 | G | 10 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 2 | 102 | F | 2 | 3 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 2 | 102 | G | 0 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 3 | 103 | F | 3 | 6 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 3 | 103 | G | 0 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 4 | 104 | F | 4 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 4 | 104 | G | 0 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 5 | 105 | F | 5 | 15 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 5 | 105 | G | 0 | 10 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 6 | 106 | F | 2 | 17 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 6 | 106 | G | 1 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 7 | 107 | F | 2 | 19 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 7 | 107 | G | 0 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 8 | 108 | F | 3 | 22 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 8 | 108 | G | 0 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 9 | 109 | F | 1 | 23 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 9 | 109 | G | 0 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 10 | 1010 | F | 2 | 25 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 10 | 1010 | G | 0 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 11 | 1011 | F | 1 | 26 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 11 | 1011 | G | 0 | 11 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 12 | 1012 | F | 3 | 29 |
| 2021 | 6394 | 12 | 1012 | G | 0 | 11 |

i have tried this

```
WITH temp1 AS
(select   year,invoiceID,locationID,count(1)
FROM     InputTable
GROUP BY year, invoiceID,ocationID HAVING   count(1)=1)
,
temp2 AS
(  SELECT *  FROM   InputTable
  WHERE  concat(year,'_',invoiceID,'_',locationID) in 
      (  SELECT   concat(b.year, '_',b.invoiceID,'_',b.locationID)  FROM    InputTable b
                   GROUP BY b.year,  b.invoiceID, b.locationID
                   HAVING   count (1)>1 
      ) 
) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
  c.year,
                CASE  WHEN c.code=d.code THEN c.post_date_month  ELSE c.post_date_month END AS post_date_month,
                c.invoiceID,
                CASE WHEN c.code=d.code THEN c.locationID  ELSE d.locationID END AS locationID,
                CASE WHEN c.code=d.code THEN c.code  ELSE d.code END AS code,
                CASE  WHEN c.code=d.code THEN c.base_amount ELSE d.base_amount END AS base_amount,
                CASE  WHEN c.code=d.code THEN c.base_amount_ytd  ELSE d.base_amount_ytd  END AS base_amount_ytd
FROM            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT b.*
                                FROM            temp1 a
                                INNER JOIN      InputTable b
                                ON              a.year=b.year   AND  a.invoiceID=b.invoiceID AND a.locationID=b.locationID
                ) c
LEFT JOIN       temp2 d
ON              1=1
;
```

Comment: Give <> SQL Server; what are you *really* using? I have removed the conflicting tags for the time being. I also don't see what this has to do with [[tag:etl]] (Extract Transform Load), so i have removed that tag too. Don't tag spam; it doesn't help us help you.

Comment: What have *you* tried to solve the problem too? Why didn't it work? [Edit] your question to include your attempt(s) and details of why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First you need all the rows that have a COUNT(*) of 1 in the cte where you build the "new" rows and union that to te existing rows.

From your example i have build the CTE, that fits your data, but you need to adept the CTE to your needs

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Year,   LocationID,     Month,  invoiceID, 'G',0,
        CASE WHEN "amt ytd" > 10 THEN 11 ELSE 10 END
    FROM InputTable
    GROUP BY Year,  LocationID,     Month,invoiceID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
SELECT * FROM InputTable
UNION 
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY Year,  LocationID,     Month,  invoiceID
```